# Multiply/Concatenate String Arrays

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

Suppose I have three columns importing data from elsewhere, like so:

| Name | Company | Division |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Meta | Ops |
| Betty | Nvidia | Sales |
| Carl | OpenAI | Development |

The number of values in each column may change from time to time as the report is run.
I want to create a column that combines the data in such a way:

| Combined |
| --- |
| Adam - Meta - Ops |
| Adam - Meta - Sales |
| Adam - Meta - Development |
| Adam - Nvidia - Ops |
| Adam - Nvidia - Sales |
| Adam - Nvidia - Development |
| Adam - OpenAI - Ops |
| Adam - OpenAI - Sales |
| Adam - OpenAI - Development |
| Betty - Meta - Ops |
| Betta - Meta - Sales |
| Betty - Meta - Development |
| Betty - Nvidia - Ops |

.... etc.

I've tried various setups with arrayformula concat() with no luck. I was hoping this could be solved with just formulas and not needing any scripting.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is very efficient in case you need to use larger data sets:

```
LET(a,A1:A, b,B1:B, c,C1:C,
  qr,LAMBDA(q, FILTER(q,q<>"")),
  calc,LAMBDA(x,y, TOCOL(TOROW(
    BYROW(x, LAMBDA(r, TOROW(ARRAYFORMULA(r&" - "&y))))))),
  calc(calc(qr(a), qr(b)), qr(c)))
```

1. `a`,`b`, & `c` store the three ranges containing the values. They are each single columns, and do not need to be the same height.
2. `qr` is a reusable LAMBDA function to remove blank rows from the ranges.
3. `calc` is a reusable LAMBDA function that expects two inputs, `x` and `y`, that are each single column arrays (or ranges) and can be the same or different heights.
4. `calc` uses BYROW to pass each value in `x`, one-by-one, into another LAMBDA function that stores the current value (row) in `r`.
5. That nested LAMBDA's ARRAYFORMULA returns a one-column array where each value is `r` joined to a different member of `y` delimited by  `-` . The result of that ARRAYFORMULA is transformed into a row using TOROW.
6. Once the LAMBDA's formula has been applied to each `r`, the two-dimensional array it returns has as many rows as there are in `x` and as many columns as in `y`.
7. `calc` then transforms that two-dimensional array to a single column using TOCOL
8. The last step is to call `calc` twice. Note that `a`, `b`, and `c`, are wrapped in `qr` to strip out any empty rows.

   1. The first `calc` is the nested one, where `x=qr(a)` and `y=qr(b)`.
   2. The second `calc` is the outer one, where `x` is the array returned by the inner `calc` and `y=qr(c)`

   - Note that additional rows and/or columns can be added nesting the outer `calc` within another `calc`, as was done for `c`

[BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en)  [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)  [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en)  [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en)  [TOROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187459?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to create a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of three sets. Assuming the data is in `A2:C`, try something like this:

```
=let( 
  table, A2:C, 
  blank, iferror(1/0), 
  first_, lambda(array, tocol(choosecols(array, 1), true)), 
  rest_, lambda(n, choosecols(table, sequence(1, columns(table) - n, n + 1))), 
  wrap_, lambda(array, wrapCount, wraprows(tocol(array, true), wrapCount)), 

  cartesian_, lambda(a, b, wrap_( 
    byrow(a, lambda(row, 
      reduce(blank, sequence(rows(b)), lambda(acc, i, 
        { acc, row, chooserows(b, i) } 
      ) ) 
    ) ), 
    columns(a) + columns(b) 
  ) ), 

  iterate_, lambda( 
    self, a, b, if(iserror(b), a, 
      self(self, cartesian_(a, first_(b)), rest_(columns(a) + 1)) 
    ) 
  ), 

  iterate_(iterate_, first_(table), rest_(1)) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914),
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244),
[wraprows()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285)
and
[reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `cart`esian `prod`uct by just  concatting (`&`) first array with the `TRANSPOSE`d second array and then `FLATTEN`ning the result:

```
=LET(
  cart_prod, 
    LAMBDA(
      a,
      b, 
      FLATTEN(
        ARRAYFORMULA(a&" - "&TRANSPOSE(b))
      )
    ), 
  ab, cart_prod(A2:A4,B2:B4),
  cart_prod(ab, C2:C4) 
)
```

We can use `REDUCE` to iterate, if you have multiple columns.